# Copy lines and replace beginning of some lines

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a file containing lines of the form

```
this is block 1
a 1 2 3
this is block 2
a 3 1 9
this is block 3
a 10 2 32
...
```

I would like to copy some of the lines and replace the beginning so that it becomes:

```
this is block 1
a 1 2 3
b 1 2 3
c 1 2 3
this is block 2
a 3 1 9
b 3 1 9
c 3 1 9
this is block 3
a 10 2 32
b 10 2 32
c 10 2 32
...
```

Not sure how to solve this with awk, sed or another elegant option.

Comment: Completely possible with **awk** but I can't see where lines beginning with `b` and `c` are coming from.

Comment: Should be very simple with `awk`. If the line begins with `a`, print the line, then `$1 = "b"`, print it again, then `$1 = "c"`, print it again.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! The lines starting with b and c are just copies of the lines starting with a, but with the a being replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed` or `awk` you can do it in this way:

```
$ cat data 
this is block 1
a 1 2 3
this is block 2
a 3 1 9
this is block 3
a 10 2 32
$ sed -rn '/^a/{p;s/^a/b/;p;s/^b/c/;p;n};p' data 
this is block 1
a 1 2 3
b 1 2 3
c 1 2 3
this is block 2
a 3 1 9
b 3 1 9
c 3 1 9
this is block 3
a 10 2 32
b 10 2 32
c 10 2 32
$ awk '{if($1=="a") {print;$1="b";print;$1="c";print} else {print}}' data 
this is block 1
a 1 2 3
b 1 2 3
c 1 2 3
this is block 2
a 3 1 9
b 3 1 9
c 3 1 9
this is block 3
a 10 2 32
b 10 2 32
c 10 2 32
$
```

Comment: Awesome, that works, thanks a lot!